# Powershell Command to Export Sent Items Count in Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange, powershell

I'm looking to get a count of all sent items for each user in our organization. We are doing an audit of all users to find out which culprit has been sending out tons of emails, so this is why I'm asking.

If anyone has a cmdlet or syntax that will help me achieve this, it would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Are you after a count of items in their "Sent Mail" box, or are you something outside of that? e.g. if they delete the emails from Sent Mail

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on organicit's answer, [you can find a script to do what you want here](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/bb94b422-eb9e-4c53-a454-f7da6ddfb5d6).

Note that this script has a serious bug - it only works with North American dates. Got your server set to use *anything* else (for example, dd/mm/yyyy, like you know, the rest of the entire world) and it doesn't work.

To run it, I just changed my locale to United States, and then changed it back after the script ran.

Script is as follows below:

```csh
#mjolinor 
#02/24/2011 

#requires -version 2.0 

$today = get-date 
$rundate = $($today.adddays(-1)).toshortdatestring() 

$outfile_date = ([datetime]$rundate).tostring("yyyy_MM_dd") 
$outfile = "email_stats_" + $outfile_date + ".csv" 

$dl_stat_file = "DL_stats.csv" 

$accepted_domains = Get-AcceptedDomain |% {$_.domainname.domain} 
[regex]$dom_rgx = "`(?i)(?:" + (($accepted_domains |% {"@" + [regex]::escape($_)}) -join "|") + ")$" 

$mbx_servers = Get-ExchangeServer |? {$_.serverrole -match "Mailbox"}|% {$_.fqdn} 
[regex]$mbx_rgx = "`(?i)(?:" + (($mbx_servers |% {"@" + [regex]::escape($_)}) -join "|") + ")\>$" 

$msgid_rgx = "^\<.+@.+\..+\>$" 

$hts = get-exchangeserver |? {$_.serverrole -match "hubtransport"} |% {$_.name} 

$exch_addrs = @{} 

$msgrec = @{} 
$bytesrec = @{} 

$msgrec_exch = @{} 
$bytesrec_exch = @{} 

$msgrec_smtpext = @{} 
$bytesrec_smtpext = @{} 

$total_msgsent = @{} 
$total_bytessent = @{} 
$unique_msgsent = @{} 
$unique_bytessent = @{} 

$total_msgsent_exch = @{} 
$total_bytessent_exch = @{} 
$unique_msgsent_exch = @{} 
$unique_bytessent_exch = @{} 

$total_msgsent_smtpext = @{} 
$total_bytessent_smtpext = @{} 
$unique_msgsent_smtpext=@{} 
$unique_bytessent_smtpext = @{} 

$dl = @{} 


$obj_table = { 
@" 
Date = $rundate 
User = $($address.split("@")[0]) 
Domain = $($address.split("@")[1]) 
Sent Total = $(0 + $total_msgsent[$address]) 
Sent MB Total = $("{0:F2}" -f $($total_bytessent[$address]/1mb)) 
Received Total = $(0 + $msgrec[$address]) 
Received MB Total = $("{0:F2}" -f $($bytesrec[$address]/1mb)) 
Sent Internal = $(0 + $total_msgsent_exch[$address]) 
Sent Internal MB = $("{0:F2}" -f $($total_bytessent_exch[$address]/1mb)) 
Sent External = $(0 + $total_msgsent_smtpext[$address]) 
Sent External MB = $("{0:F2}" -f $($total_bytessent_smtpext[$address]/1mb)) 
Received Internal = $(0 + $msgrec_exch[$address]) 
Received Internal MB = $("{0:F2}" -f $($bytesrec_exch[$address]/1mb)) 
Received External = $(0 + $msgrec_smtpext[$address]) 
Received External MB = $("{0:F2}" -f $($bytesrec_smtpext[$address]/1mb)) 
Sent Unique Total = $(0 + $unique_msgsent[$address]) 
Sent Unique MB Total = $("{0:F2}" -f $($unique_bytessent[$address]/1mb)) 
Sent Internal Unique  = $(0 + $unique_msgsent_exch[$address])  
Sent Internal Unique MB = $("{0:F2}" -f $($unique_bytessent_exch[$address]/1mb)) 
Sent External  Unique = $(0 + $unique_msgsent_smtpext[$address]) 
Sent External Unique MB = $("{0:F2}" -f $($unique_bytessent_smtpext[$address]/1mb)) 
"@ 
} 

$props = $obj_table.ToString().Split("`n")|% {if ($_ -match "(.+)="){$matches[1].trim()}} 

$stat_recs = @() 

function time_pipeline { 
param ($increment  = 1000) 
begin{$i=0;$timer = [diagnostics.stopwatch]::startnew()} 
process { 
    $i++ 
    if (!($i % $increment)){Write-host “`rProcessed $i in $($timer.elapsed.totalseconds) seconds” -nonewline} 
    $_ 
    } 
end { 
    write-host “`rProcessed $i log records in $($timer.elapsed.totalseconds) seconds” 
    Write-Host "   Average rate: $([int]($i/$timer.elapsed.totalseconds)) log recs/sec." 
    } 
} 

foreach ($ht in $hts){ 

    Write-Host "`nStarted processing $ht" 

    get-messagetrackinglog -Server $ht -Start "$rundate" -End "$rundate 11:59:59 PM" -resultsize unlimited | 
    time_pipeline |%{ 


    if ($_.eventid -eq "DELIVER" -and $_.source -eq "STOREDRIVER"){ 

        if ($_.messageid -match $mbx_rgx -and $_.sender -match $dom_rgx) { 

            $total_msgsent[$_.sender] += $_.recipientcount 
            $total_bytessent[$_.sender] += ($_.recipientcount * $_.totalbytes) 
            $total_msgsent_exch[$_.sender] += $_.recipientcount 
            $total_bytessent_exch[$_.sender] += ($_.totalbytes * $_.recipientcount) 

            foreach ($rcpt in $_.recipients){ 
            $exch_addrs[$rcpt] ++ 
            $msgrec[$rcpt] ++ 
            $bytesrec[$rcpt] += $_.totalbytes 
            $msgrec_exch[$rcpt] ++ 
            $bytesrec_exch[$rcpt] += $_.totalbytes 
            } 

        } 

        else { 
            if ($_messageid -match $messageid_rgx){ 
                    foreach ($rcpt in $_.recipients){ 
                        $msgrec[$rcpt] ++ 
                        $bytesrec[$rcpt] += $_.totalbytes 
                        $msgrec_smtpext[$rcpt] ++ 
                        $bytesrec_smtpext[$rcpt] += $_.totalbytes 
                    } 
                } 

            } 

    } 


    if ($_.eventid -eq "RECEIVE" -and $_.source -eq "STOREDRIVER"){ 
        $exch_addrs[$_.sender] ++ 
        $unique_msgsent[$_.sender] ++ 
        $unique_bytessent[$_.sender] += $_.totalbytes 

            if ($_.recipients -match $dom_rgx){ 
                $unique_msgsent_exch[$_.sender] ++ 
                $unique_bytessent_exch[$_.sender] += $_.totalbytes 
                } 

            if ($_.recipients -notmatch $dom_rgx){ 
                $ext_count = ($_.recipients -notmatch $dom_rgx).count 
                $unique_msgsent_smtpext[$_.sender] ++ 
                $unique_bytessent_smtpext[$_.sender] += $_.totalbytes 
                $total_msgsent[$_.sender] += $ext_count 
                $total_bytessent[$_.sender] += ($ext_count * $_.totalbytes) 
                $total_msgsent_smtpext[$_.sender] += $ext_count 
                 $total_bytessent_smtpext[$_.sender] += ($ext_count * $_.totalbytes) 
                } 


        } 

    if ($_.eventid -eq "expand"){ 
        $dl[$_.relatedrecipientaddress] ++ 
        } 
    }      

} 

foreach ($address in $exch_addrs.keys){ 

$stat_rec = (new-object psobject -property (ConvertFrom-StringData (&$obj_table))) 
$stat_recs += $stat_rec | select $props 
} 

$stat_recs | export-csv $outfile -notype  

if (Test-Path $dl_stat_file){ 
    $DL_stats = Import-Csv $dl_stat_file 
    $dl_list = $dl_stats |% {$_.address} 
    } 

else { 
    $dl_list = @() 
    $DL_stats = @() 
    } 


$DL_stats |% { 
    if ($dl[$_.address]){ 
        if ([datetime]$_.lastused -le [datetime]$rundate){  
            $_.used = [int]$_.used + [int]$dl[$_.address] 
            $_.lastused = $rundate 
            } 
        } 
} 

$dl.keys |% { 
    if ($dl_list -notcontains $_){ 
        $new_rec = "" | select Address,Used,Since,LastUsed 
        $new_rec.address = $_ 
        $new_rec.used = $dl[$_] 
        $new_rec.Since = $rundate 
        $new_rec.lastused = $rundate 
        $dl_stats += @($new_rec) 
    } 
} 

$dl_stats | Export-Csv $dl_stat_file -NoTypeInformation -force 


Write-Host "`nRun time was $(((get-date) - $today).totalseconds) seconds." 
Write-Host "Email stats file is $outfile" 
Write-Host "DL usage stats file is $dl_stat_file" 


#Contact information 
#[string](0..33|%{[char][int](46+("686552495351636652556262185355647068516270555358646562655775 0645570").substring(($_*2),2))})-replace " "
```

Comment: So running this script, where is the csv files store?

Comment: Mine ended up on the desktop, but that's also where the script ran from.

Answer (score -2):

found this "Hey Scripting Guy" article that may provide your answer.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/03/02/use-powershell-to-track-email-messages-in-exchange-server.aspx

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: agreed. I am new to powershell so I am interested to see if our feedback helps Jimmy.